# Simple Chart with X,Y Axis values

Tags: reporting, charts

[image]

I have a custom object record with two fields (one date and another weight value).

I am at a loss to understand how such a simple requirement of creating a chart (X: Date, Y: Weight) with those two values is not possible in Salesforce.

The chart component does not even appear unless I group one of the two values.

And even if I choose "Date" field value to group it does not even allow me to display the "Weight" data but allows me to display only "Record Count".

Surely I must be missing..right ?...There must be a way ,without resorting to code, to create this graph.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to first group the two fields, and then summarize them:

[image]

Since there is only one value for each date in this case, any of min, max or average should work for you since they will all be the same. Then when you build the chart, you will get the option to use that min/max/average as the y-value.