# Report Summary type with Chart having custom field in Y axis

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, report-chart, report-builder

I need to create a Report of summary type with a custom field in Y axis. But every time I try do that getting only option as Record Count.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve that?

Below in **Y axis** I get only **Record Count** but I require to have Column values there.

[image]

Comment: You sure you have that field included in the report and aggregated? You might want to add whatever you have done till now as screenshots.

Comment: Something like this? [Simple Chart with X,Y Axis values](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/93087/20941)

Comment: I just need in Y axis a custom field rather than Record Count

Comment: This is starting to sound a lot like a duplicate question to me. Is what you are trying to do different from the link I attached?

Comment: Ah well in the link they say about min max etc of field. I just need to make the field plotted in Y axis. I am attaching the screenshot from my system for better understanding.

Comment: But if there's only one record, the min and max will both be the y value.

Comment: @martin  Please find my updated screenshot from the Report. I did group by Record Type which is fine for me. Only thing is how to get custom fields on Y axis.

Comment: I got the correct answer here.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gqgVAAQ

We need to summarize fields to make it available on chart axis.  Thanks @martin

Comment: no problem. I hope I was able to help.